# How to share Note object record to a user using Apex sharing

Tags: apex-managed-sharing, notes

Is it possible to share Note object record to a user using Apex sharing.I am not able to find sharing object for Note like Accountshare which is used for Account.

Comment: I think you have to share the parent.